# How to merge a shape into text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I have some text and a shape created in photoshop.  I am trying to do some blending options to the shape and then merge it into the text, so that the shape disappears, apart from the bit that is inside the text.

How do I achieve this?

This is what I have right now:

[image]

I want this rectangle to disappear into the text so I can just see the text and the shape part inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click *between* the two layers in the **Layers Panel**....

[image]

You should see a little downward arrow in the Layers Panel and the top layer's thumbnail should shift right slightly in the Layers Panel, indicating the *Clipping Mask* you've created.

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat.  Been bothering me for two days!